# Integration proof: sin(1/x) is integrable

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Question:

> Let $f : [a,b] \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded function. Suppose $f$ is integrable on $[a,r]$ for all $a<r<b$. Show that $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ and prove that $$a) \;\; \int_{a}^b f(x) dx = \lim_{r\rightarrow b^-}\int_{a}^r f(x)dx$$ Use this result to justify that the function $f:[0,1]\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ defined by: $$b) \;\; f(x) = \begin{cases}\sin \left(\frac{1}{x}\right) & 0 < x \leq 1\\0 & x = 0\end{cases}$$ is integrable.

I have proven that $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ by showing that there exist a partition $P'$ of $[a,b]$ with $U(P′,f)−L(P′,f)< \epsilon$ ($\epsilon$ arbitrary) and now I don't know where to start to prove the problem a) ...

please refer to the image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Rl0S.jpg

Comment: @Anthony Peter In the answer of the post I mention, there are solutions for both points.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Ah, apologies, I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Since $f$ is integrable on $[a,r]$ for each $r$, and $f$ is bounded, let $M$ be such a bound. Then, take $r$ sufficiently close to $b$ so that, even if $f$ behaves as badly as $M$ at $b$, this behaviour is negligible and hence $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ by this partition.

It's the common trick of either (i) controlling $f$ where you know it's values or (ii) controlling the intervals on which the values of $f$ are unknown yet bounded.

For the second part, prove that $$|\int_{a}^{b} f \, dx - \int_{a}^{r} f \, dx | < \epsilon$$ for $r$ sufficiently close to $b$.

If you need further hints I'd be happy to provide them.

Comment: can you provide me some hint for the second part ? I'm not really familiar with limit that involves integral thank you

Comment: @Sonia No limits needed, just choose your partitions right and use the fact that since they're both integrable, you can find an upper and lower sum really close to the value of the integral by definition of sup and inf